# grep string from Message in Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell

I have a script to check the event logs from `get-winevent`, I need to show the complete results of `get-winevent` output based on search string from message column.

Is there any way to grep Message column in `get-winevent`

This is the current string

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Target_Machine -FilterHashtable $params
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipeline output to Where-object, see example below:

```
$SearchString="AutoConfig"                                                                                                                                                                             
Get-WinEvent Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational | Where-Object{$_.Message -like "*$SearchString*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SearchString="your sting"                                                                                                                                                                             
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security'} |Where-Object -Property Message -Match $SearchString

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application'} |Where-Object -Property Message -Match $SearchString

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Setup'} |Where-Object -Property Message -Match $SearchString

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='System'} |Where-Object -Property Message -Match $SearchString
```